# Override urlpattern in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Trying to alter url for some of Django's application views, but replacing of `urlpatterns` list seems to have no effect:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from myapp.contact.urls import urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns

print [u for u in urlpatterns if 'user_account_info' == str(getattr(u,'name',''))]
# [<RegexURLPattern user_account_info ^$>]
print reverse('user_account_info', current_app='myapp.contact.views'
# '/accounts/'

# Create url pattern replacement
patt=patterns('myapp.contact.views', (r'^konto/$', 'view', {}, 'user_account_info') )
print patt
# [<RegexURLPattern user_account_info ^konto/$>]

for ix in range(len(urlpatterns)):
    if hasattr(urlpatterns[ix], 'name') and \
            urlpatterns[ix].name == 'user_account_info':
        del urlpatterns[ix]
        urlpatterns.insert(0, patt)
        print 'done !'

print [u for u in urlpatterns if 'user_account_info' == str(getattr(u,'name',''))]
# [<RegexURLPattern user_account_info ^konto/$>]
# seems replacement was made ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

print reverse('user_account_info', current_app='myapp.contact.views'
# '/accounts/'
```

Why `reverse` still returns the old path ? Any idea ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Why do you want to modify the urlconf dynamically?

Comment: I need to customize urls of the project and can not directly alter urls.py of 3rd party applications (ie. can't modify their sources).

Comment: That sounds counter-intuitive. You should be modifying urls.py instead. Why can you not change third-party application URLs?

Comment: @Joe I don't think so. At the Django hosting, there are installed & updated packages project depends on and can not be modified. Sure, I can also install them in project's virtualenv, however it would require to take care of their updates by myself. Just ask if it's possible to change url paths of external applications at my local project initialization.